# how to change the input mode of the mobile using j2me (MIDP2.0)?

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I am working in j2me midp2.0 environment. Now, I want to draw String (custom item) based on user key pressed event. Here, my problem is, some phones default input mode is numeric and I can't be able to draw Strings. How to change this input mode to Strings and vice versa?

Comment: @Derzu : Sorry, couldn't able to get the solution...

Answer (score -1):

I think you manually get the key values and change it. On key press event you find which key pressed based on that you write a login to get numeric values or character, etc.